# Python - TypeHint for Descriptor

Tags: python, python-typing, python-descriptors

I would like to have a base class for all my descriptors which is of type descriptor:

1. Is it correct to use the GetSetDescriptorType?

```
class MyDescriptorBase(GetSetDescriptorType):
  pass
```

Now when I declare

```
class MyDescriptor(DescriptorBase):

    def __get__(self, __obj: MyObj, objtype: Type[MyObj] ):
       pass
```

A pycharm inspection complains:

> **get**() does not match signature.

I have looked up the signature which is:

```
# types.pyi

def __get__(self, __obj: Any, __type: type = ...) -> Any: ...
```

2. Is it an error in inspection or is my declaration wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using `GetSetDescriptor` class as base is invalid for type checking since this class is [final](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/types.pyi#L584=).

You don't really need this base, because descriptors have good support now.

The problem in your definition is missing default value of `objtype`: parent can be called with one argument and your child - no, so this violates LSP. So the following is compatible:

```py
class MyDescriptor(MyDescriptorBase):
    def __get__(self, obj: MyObj, objtype: type[MyObj] | None = None):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, @SUTerliakov : How would I describe for others that any class inheriting from `MyDescriptorBase` is supposed to be a descriptor? Or is there no descriptor type in `typing`?

Comment: If you need this for documentation purposes, then name `MyDescriptorBase` is descriptive enough, plus you can add a docstring. If you need to ensure that all children implement `__get__` and `__set__` - use `abc.ABC` as base class and decorate `__get__` and `__set__` with `@abstractmethod`.